# Nested Tab Menue with jQuery / CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have to make a site about statistics and therefore I need a 4 level nested tab menu. (Dates/Routes/Categories/Disziplins)

Here I found something for 2 levels, but I can't alter it for more levels :( 
I hope someone will find a solution :)

Thanks a lot!

```
$("ul.nav-tabs a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

```
<div class="tabbable boxed parentTabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#set1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#set2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="set1">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#sub11">Tab 1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#sub12">Tab 1.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="sub11">
                        <p>Tab 1.1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub12">
                        <p>Tab 1.2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set2">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#sub21">Tab 2.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#sub22">Tab 2.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="sub21">
                        <p>Tab 2.1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub22">
                        <p>Tab 2.2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written some code for tabs which can further edited to add more levels. See if this helps.

JS:

```
    $('.tabs a').click(function(){
    var idd = $(this).attr('href');

    if($(idd).hasClass('tabs_content')) //First Level
    {
        $('.tabs_content').hide();
        $(idd).fadeIn();
        $(idd).find('.tabs ul li:first a').click();
        $('.tabs:first ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    }else if($(idd).hasClass('tab_content_inner')) //Second Level
    {
        $('.tab_content_inner').hide();
        $(idd).fadeIn();
        $(idd).find('.tabs ul li:first a').click();
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    }else if($(idd).hasClass('tab_content_inner_inner')) //3rd Level
    {
        $('.tab_content_inner_inner').hide();
        $(idd).fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/PERQ9/1/)

It can be done more logically to reduce the redundant code.

Comment: thanks that looks really nice! My problem here is that i have a date picker like http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. so with your code, i have to make nested divs for each day. Do you know a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @karan3112's answer, I was able to come up with a better solution, which supports unlimited nesting. The following script locates the appropriate elements relatively without need for additional classes like `tab_content_inner`.

```
$('.tabs a').click(function ()
{
    var anchor = $(this);

    var tabs = $(anchor).parent().parent().parent();
    $(tabs).find('li > a').removeClass('active');

    select_tab(anchor)
});

$('.tabs a.active').each(function()
{
    select_tab(this)
});

function select_tab(anchor)
{
    if (!$(anchor).hasClass('active'))
        $(anchor).addClass('active');

    var li = $(anchor).parent();
    var ul = $(li).parent();

    var tabs = $(ul).parent();
    var index = $(li).index();

    var form = $(tabs).parent();

    var contents = $(form).find('> .tabs-content');
    $(contents).hide().eq(index).fadeIn();
}
```

First, we show the tab that is active (if one is) for each 'tab set' this is because all content is hidden initially using CSS. We find the associated tab content relative to the tab anchor by getting the index of the content relative to it's immediate parent (note, indexing is obviously the key here).

The HTML structure is exactly the same as the example my solution is based on except you don't need to specify special classes for nested tab sets; now, you only have to work with the three main classes: `tabs`, `tabs-content`, and `active`.